# how to show tootltips at multiple point in one click in d3

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, scatter-plot

I have created a scatter plot that contains two sets of data for a particular item A namely [x,y1] and [x,y2] . Through the 'onmouseover' function i want to show the tooltip of both the values y1 and y2 of a simultaneously.Suppose I hover over point (x,y1) of A then it should show the tooltip of both points (x,y1) and (x,y2) of A and vice-versa. I have used the following code snippet:

```
 .on('mouseover',function(d){tip_1.show(d) + tip_2.show(d)});
```

It is working but its printing both the tool-tips at one point only instead of showing it in their respective positions.
I have written two different tooltip functions for both the data set.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide code of tooltip show functions.

Comment: var tip_1= d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .style("fill",function(d,i){return z(i)})
  .html(function(d) {
    return  d.y1;});
 
var tip_2=d3.tip()
    .attr('class','d3-tip_1')
 .offset([-10,0])
 .style("fill",function(d,i){return z(i)})
 .html(function(d){
    return  d.y2;});

Comment: You can edit your question and provide there all the necessary information.